# AVPlayer not showing FullScreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am working on playing a recorded video recorded by **AVCapture**.I am saving the video URL in string named **outputFileURL**. I tried playing back the video using **AVPlayerLayer** concept. The code I used is

```
AVPlayer *avPlayerq = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:outputFileURL];
avPlayerq.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
AVPlayerLayer *videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayerq];
videoLayer.frame= self.view.bounds;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[avPlayerq play];
```

But the video I am getting is not full screen.
Can anyone can help me to solve?

Comment: try this   [playerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

Comment: Thank you. It work fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I added the following code and I am able to get the full screen.

```
videoLayer.videoGravity=AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
```

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new]; playerViewController.delegate = self; 
playerViewController.player = player; 
[playerViewController.player play]; 
[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Try This

Ok than you have to use MPMoviePlayerController

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Video_Intro" ofType:@"mov"];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = ivVideoThumbnail.frame;

    //moviePlayer.view.top += 20; // Add to fix 20 pixel diff of moviePlayer view


    // Register this class as an observer instead.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];


    [svIntro addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = true;
    [moviePlayer play];
```

Also implement Observer method

```
-(void)movieFinishedCallback:(id)mPlayer
{
    [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: I am working on a device which has version iOS7. AVPlayerViewController doesn't support iOS7, it supports iOS8+.

Comment: I previously tried using MPMoviePlayerController. I got too many issues using that. So I want to switch to AVPlayerLayer.